# How can I set the starting conditions to give myself more of an advantage against the AI in Defcon?

Tags: defcon

I've just started playing Defcon, and I've been learning the game by playing against the AI.

The AI is tough.  I keep getting my behind handed to me.  This is, shall we say, not optimal.

There's nothing that allows you to set the difficulty of the AI players, but I'm wondering if there's a way to slightly cripple the AI somehow using the starting conditions - perhaps there is a particular territory that it doesn't play very well or that it has difficulty defending against.

I already tried going two-on-one with an allied AI against a lone AI player, which didn't teach me anything because it was much too easy.  I'm not looking for a curbstomp, I just want to keep the AI from curbstomping me long enough to learn to play.

**Is there a way to set up the starting conditions of a Defcon game to give the AI a more difficult time, without completely crippling it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one thing I've found to work well is positioning.

To give yourself an advantage against the AI, **play as Europe against Africa.**